# How do we read an edited EditText field value inside a ListView item upon a button click?

Tags: android

In this adapter class, I am trying to read user-entered EditText values upon button click. Both EditText and button are inside a ListView item. What is the best way to read that value? The way I have tried below did not capture the correct value from the EditText field.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    box = null;
    db = new database(getContext());

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        box = new container();
        box.X = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_X);
        box.Y = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_Y);
        box.Z = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);
        box.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_button);
        convertView.setTag(box);
    }

    else
    {
        box = (container) convertView.getTag();
    }

    box.X.setText( getItem(position).getX() );
    box.Y.setText( String.valueOf(getItem(position).getY()) );

    box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            View view = View.inflate( getContext(), R.layout.activity_manage, null );
            string_is = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);
            value_is = new Integer( string_is.getText().toString() );

            // In my ListView, I have an item with 1 EditText and a button. 
            // User can enter a value for Z, which is EditText.
            // I want to read that value upon button click and do things with it.
            // My above method does not capture the correct Z value.
    });

    return convertView;
}

public class container
{
    TextView X;
    TextView Y;
    TextView Z;
    Button button;
}
```

Comment: share screenshot...

Comment: View view = View.inflate( getContext(), R.layout.activity_manage, null ); why inflate layout in adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing `editText.addOnTextChangedListener()` just like you set the OnClickListener for your button. On every text changed, store the changed string in some string variable and access the variable when you click the button.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented  addTextChangedListener()  and it's working well with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should not reinflate you view again, this will create a new view and your findViewById will return a new View.

Your code with the correction:

```
box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        string_is = (EditText) box.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);
        value_is = new Integer( string_is.getText().toString() );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! Removing the repeated inflation worked. However, then I had another issue as I have explained below...

Answer (score 0):

```
box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    string_is = (EditText)box.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);
    value_is = new Integer( string_is.getText().toString() );
  }
});
```

Above worked. But I ran into a strange issue. I can only read the editText value of the 2nd listView item. I have several items in the list and when I click the other buttons, they give the following error message:

W/IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection

W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.

D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.

Comment: Can you post your entire logcat?