# Why do entered editText values get copied into other listView item editText fields upon scrolling?

Tags: android

This question derived from [How do we read an edited EditText field value inside a ListView item upon a button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961976/how-do-we-read-an-edited-edittext-field-value-inside-a-listview-item-upon-a-butt/40962125#40962125)

In this adapter class, I am reading user-entered EditText values upon button click. Both EditText and button are inside a ListView item.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    box = null;
    db = new database(getContext());

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        box = new container();
        box.X = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_X);
        box.Y = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_Y);
        box.Z = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);
        box.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manage_button);
        convertView.setTag(box);
    }

    else
    {
        box = (container) convertView.getTag();
    }

    box.X.setText( getItem(position).getX() );
    box.Y.setText( String.valueOf(getItem(position).getY()) );

    string_is = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.manage_Z);

    string_is.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count ) {}

        @Override public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) {}

        @Override public void afterTextChanged( Editable s ) 
        { 
             to_remove = new Integer( s.toString() ); 
        }
    });

    box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
             // I am using the to_remove value here for calculations.
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public class container
{
    TextView X;
    TextView Y;
    TextView Z;
    Button button;
}
```

I want to find solutions to the following questions:

## 01:

I have multiple list items. When I entered a value in the first item's editText, the same value gets copied in another editText field as I scroll down. When I scroll up again, the initially entered values get different ones based on what I had entered into the other fields.

The same issue has been addressed at [EditText in listview repeats the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333037/edittext-in-listview-repeats-the-value)

but adding **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** did not solve my issue.

```
<application

    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".item" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".database" />
    <activity android:name=".unit" />
    <activity android:name=".loader" />
    <activity android:name=".block"></activity>
</application>
```

## 02:

As a workaround to resolve the above issue, I used...

> string_is.setText("");

inside...

> box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
>
> @Override public void onClick(View v) {} );

I just wanted the editText field that I just entered to be reset upon button click and to show no value, which makes it ready for another value to be edited. And that is without having to delete the previously entered value by doing backspaces, which makes the program to halt after backspacing the first digit due to the use of the **addTextChangedListener()**. I don't understand why I cannot set the text inside the **onClick()** listener. This solution will help me to not to worry about editText fields getting copied while scrolling.

Comment: Listview is focusable component and one most important issue that scrolling, while you scroll the listview that time getView() is called so that in getView() method all the data will reset from the ArrayList. So that if you have not used the addTextChangedListener, EditText should do misbehave. So that in addTextChangedListener we should save the edittext data in addTextChangedListner. Sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: I did use the addTextChangedListener() and I am still seeing the issue. Thanks @Mavya.

Comment: You have not set data of edittext in addTextChangedListener. You have to set the data of editText in Model in addTextChangedListener   @Override public void afterTextChanged( Editable s ) 
        { 
            getItem(position).setEditTextData(s.toString() ); 
        }